# Python aws error when pushing to github

Tags: django, git, macos, python-2.7, aws-cli

I tried to run a Django server (OSX CLi) and I messed some stuff up. I'm getting an error message on all pushes to Github:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/aws/bin/python2.7
  Reason: image not found
error: aws --profile default codecommit credential-helper $@ store died of signal 5
```

I'm not familiar with Python and Django, just followed the install instructions from here:

https://github.com/caciviclab/disclosure-backend

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From `disclosure-backend` code they are not using aws,  and there is no step involved `git push`, can you explain more about what exactly you are doing?

Comment: This is what's confusing me as well. I'm not attempting any AWS operations, and regardless of what repo I'm in when I push to Github I get the error. The push is successful, but I still get the error.

Comment: I think in your shell env, some script is calling `aws --profile default codecommit credential-helper`, try uninstall your awscli to see if it solve the issue. (You can reinstall awscli later)

Comment: Do this first, search your `~/.gitconfig` for `codecommit` or `aws` and remove those lines, it should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks! You rock! I should have known to check my .gitconfig. I commented out the lines below.

    `[credential]`
     `helper = !aws --profile default codecommit credential-helper $@`
     `UseHttpPath = true`

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm assuming that you're on OSX, based on the instructions. 
What seems to have happened is that when you created the virtualenv, it had a bunch of references to a version of python that has since been deleted or upgraded, hence the "image not found". 
I'd start by deactivating the virtualenv, then running `pip install --upgrade virtualenv`. If it stops working when you activate it, again, then you'll likely have to manually adjust the links.

Answer (score 0):

review your `~/.gitconfig` file. I removed an `aws --profile` entry and an httptrue line to get things working.